# Monodevelop: Porting from C#/Visual Studio: Double Click disappear

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monodevelop, double-click

For the last 2 month I've written application in C# in Visual Studio. Now i have to port that application to Linux by Monodevelop. Well, I already solved most of the porting errors, but there is one that i cant figure out. All double click and mouse double click events from Visual Studio stopped working - I even created small 1-form application that i ported to Mono with only form and one event (double click) - it also didnt work - so that means Monodevelop cant port double click events from Visual Studio ? I already checked WND_Proc function and Linux dont throw up any corresponding double-click event (it was 515 for in window and 3 hundred something on title bar...). Im already giving up and preparing for writing additional code to fix all double-click issue in my code but maybe someone has an answer.

Im using Ubuntu linux (if its neccesary i might tommorow check kernel version), MONO: 2.8.3, Visual Studio 2008 and project in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't the world moving away from double clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing mouse clicks, there are two main differences between Windows and Gtk# that you should keep in mind:

1. Gtk# does not offer a 'double-click' signals ('Events' in Windows lingo), but only single 'click' signals. **However Gdk library does implements both double-click and triple-click with its EventButton class!**
2. Gtk# differentiates between Widgets (or 'Controls' in Windows lingo) and 'Containers' (there is no direct comparable in Windows). Most widgets placed on a Gtk# form will NOT receive mouse click events. In order to receive a mouse event you need to place the widget inside a specific container - like EventBox.

Here is how you do it Gtk#:

A. Add an EventBox containter to your form (in the example below: eventbox1). You can place it behind other Widgets or since it is not visible, unless you specifically select it to be (or change its background color). You can put a widget inside the EventBox, but you are limited to only one widget, that will also get the shape and size of the EventBox.

B. Add to this EventBox the signal 'ButtonPressEvent' out of the "Common Widget Signals" (in the example below: OnEventbox1ButtonPressEvent)

Every time a mouse button (left, middle or center or a combination) is clicked inside the EventBox, it will trigger this event and the function OnEventbox1ButtonPressEvent() will be called. If you need to identify the button that was clicked while handling this event, use the uint value in: args.Event.Button typically '1' will be the left mouse button, '2' the center button and '3' the right button ('2' might be also when both left and right buttons are clicked).

By the way, mouse motion events (without a button press) are not sent by default. So if you need to sense them you will need to add the PointMotionMask as well in the first like of the code example below.

Here is a code example of the ButtonPress Event Handler (the EventBox name is 'eventbox1') catching a double-click event using the EventButton class:

```
// The following line is may not be needed but is here to show how to do it
eventbox1.GdkWindow.Events = eventbox1.GdkWindow.Events | Gdk.EventMask.ButtonPressMask;

protected void OnEventbox1ButtonPressEvent (object o, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
{
    if( ((Gdk.EventButton)args.Event).Type == Gdk.EventType.TwoButtonPress)
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play (); // Play a sound only if this is a double-click event
}
```

The order of the events received (in case of a double click) is:

1. Gdk.EventType.ButtonPress
2. Gdk.EventType.ButtonRelease
3. Gdk.EventType.ButtonPress
4. Gdk.EventType.TwoButtonPress
5. Gdk.EventType.ButtonRelease

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, i could do this. I already noticed that "Lost focus" function is not working correctly ("Focused" attribute is not changed immediately and i had to check it after 10ms timer). I simply hoped that Monodevelop is able to translate/simulate those events to linux code during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

GTK# treats double-click events differently than Windows Forms. You're going to have to write code to translate the events. If you're doing that, you may as well spend the time arguing against double-click as an idiom.